# Sum in a razor view with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, razorengine

What I want to do is a sum between two Models(razor ASP.NET). (they are created in the database) I don't want to do it in the controller, because later I want it not to modify my value.
I need to do it in the view one way or another, either by taking out the forEach. Thank you very much I hope your help.

```
<div class="cuartaParte">
        <table style="width: 100%">
          @foreach (var item in Model.PresupuestoDetalle){
          <tr> //here I want to do the sum
            <th scope="row" style="width: 70%; text-align: right">Descuento @Model.Cliente.Descuento+=@Model.DescuentoExtraPorcen%</th>
            <td>$@Model.ImporteDescuento</td>
          </tr>
          }
        </table>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the sum between two Models in the view,try to use `@()` outside `Model.Cliente.Descuento` and `Model.DescuentoExtraPorcen%`;

```
<div class="cuartaParte">
        <table style="width: 100%">
          @foreach (var item in Model.PresupuestoDetalle){
          <tr> //here I want to do the sum
            <th scope="row" style="width: 70%; text-align: right">Descuento @(Model.Cliente.Descuento+@Model.DescuentoExtraPorcen%)</th>
            <td>$@Model.ImporteDescuento</td>
          </tr>
          }
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Excuse me, could you give me an example of how to use it? I'm looking for information about it... and I found very little

Comment: Since you  want to show the sum between two Models in the view,`Model.Cliente.Descuento` and `Model.DescuentoExtraPorcen%` are  c# variables,and you can use C# code in `@()`,sum them in `@()` and then show them in the view.`@Model.Cliente.Descuento+=@Model.DescuentoExtraPorcen%` will only show the values and  conbines with `+=`.For example,if `Model.Cliente.Descuento` is 10 and `Model.DescuentoExtraPorcen%` is 1.The result of `@Model.Cliente.Descuento+=@Model.DescuentoExtraPorcen%` will be `10+=1`.